# Dynamically Label ggplot Scale_*_Identity

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aes

I am trying to create a plot where I have a unique HEX code for each individual, and I want to plot using `scale_color_identity()`. I also would like to use `labels` inside `scale_color_identity()` to get the actual name of each individual to display in the legend. I know this is possible when you specifically call strings outside of the `ggplot`, but I am trying to produce this for numerous scenarios and would like to be able to avoid that and instead call another variable in the data set that is being plotted. Example below is how I currently have to do it.

```
library(ggplot2)

FakeData <- data.frame(Name = c("Bob Jungels", "Bob Jungels","Bob Jungels", "Sepp Kuss", "Sepp Kuss", "Sepp Kuss", "Egan Bernal", "Egan Bernal", "Egan Bernal"),
                       TeamColor = c("#00ab8e", "#00ab8e", "#00ab8e", "#ffe100", "#ffe100", "#ffe100", "#b61615", "#b61615", "#b61615"),
                       Distance = c(0, 60, 120, 0, 60, 120, 0, 60, 120),
                       Place = c(1, 1, 35, 75, 17, 1, 65, 10, 3))

FakeData$Name <- factor(FakeData$Name, levels = c("Bob Jungels", "Sepp Kuss", "Egan Bernal"))

ggplot(FakeData) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Distance, y = Place, color = Name), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(FakeData %>% distinct(TeamColor) %>% .$TeamColor))
```

What I would like to do, but seems that it is not recognizing any variable inside the data set already.

```
ggplot(FakeData) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Distance, y = Place, color = TeamColor), size = 1.5) +
  scale_color_identity(labels = Name)
```

This produces an error **Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'Name' not found**

I need to apply this plot to numerous different filters of data and the first method above is not ideal for that. Has anyone tried to do what I am asking? I have looked around but not finding much out there.

Comment: Why is the first method not ideal? Personally I'd recommend using a named list instead, perhaps `scale_color_manual(values = with(distinct(FakeData, Name, TeamColor), setNames(TeamColor, Name)))`. That is, why is `scale_color_identity` strictly needed here?

Comment: It's unideal from the standpoint of making the plot reproduceable with altering the data. Let's say we filtered the data in `ggplot` data area. Then the above `scale_color_manual` function you have written would need that same filter to "FakeData" `distinct` call. I would like if there is any data changes to not have to resave the data frame, or make the change in numerous spots. This is a very simple example, but I am concerned having my graph call two different data sources technically will result in a mix up of data. I.e. @zephryl's answer below

Comment: I think my suggesting of `with(distinct(..), setNames(..))` avoids/resolves all risks of changing data, and guards against order of levels, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @r2evans’ comment that `scale_color_manual()` is likely a better solution than `scale_color_identity()`.

That said, if there’s some reason you’re wedded to `scale_color_identity()`, you can adapt their suggested approach, but this ends up being more complex. For instance, you need to convert `Name` back to character, and explicitly specify a `guide`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(FakeData) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Distance, y = Place, color = TeamColor), linewidth = 1.5) +
  scale_color_identity(
    "Name", 
    labels = with(distinct(FakeData, Name, TeamColor), setNames(as.character(Name), TeamColor)),
    guide = guide_legend()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: What happens with your graph is one of my main concerns. Since you have used `levels` without any relationship to "TeamColor" it has gone in alphabetical order and "Sepp Kuss" is now being labelled and colored as "Egan Bernal" and vis versa.

Comment: I agree with @r2evans that `scale_color_manual()` may be a better solution than `scale_color_identity()`. I read your response to their comment, but not sure I agree — I think if you map `name` to `color` and use @r2evans’ suggested code, `scale_color_manual(values = with(distinct(FakeData, Name, TeamColor), setNames(TeamColor, Name)))`, it will in fact dynamically update to reflect changes in your data.

Comment: All that said, you could adapt the approach they suggested to work with `scale_color_identity()` if you really need to - see my edited answer.